# Error: Could not find or load main class com.eventoapp.EventoappApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou com esse erro não consigo rodar minha aplicação.

---

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.eventoapp.EventoappApplication

**Minha classe**

```
package com.eventoapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EventoappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EventoappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura do seu projeto?

Comment: Como está tentando rodar a sua aplicação?

Comment: A estrutura do meu projeto está em maven.Estou rodando ele com java Application.

Comment: Está rodando pela linha de comando? Se sim, qual comando? É pela IDE? Qual? A sua classe está ok, pode ser problema com  o ambiente

Comment: Estou rodando pela IDE:Eclipse neon